# UV Map Problems

Tags: python, uv, texture-painting, blend-files

I write for the importer "unreal engine vertMesh" format, and I have a problem with understanding the process of texturing and uv maps.

I import model, shape keys, and then import the UV coords.

```
me.uv_textures.new ("uv_test")
me.uv_layers [-1] .data.foreach_set ("uv", [uv for pair in [uv [l.vertex_index] for l in me.loops] for uv in pair])
```

and immediately I see it on the model.

[image: 3d viev before open UV]

I have two problems:

1) texture is displayed correctly only on one, very simple model. With any other - bad.
[image: other model] [image: bad uv map for water model]

and use good uv map (in other soft) ->

[image: use good uv map]

2) if you open the Edit uvmaps, I see that the map is not true. texture to "intact" model is updated, and breaks.
uv cords array true 100%

[image: uv map]
[image: uvmap_3d]

How do I bring uv map in the norm?

Other model bad uv map.

[image: other model uv maps]